# C#: How to have a ToString method be printed out in the console by calling it in the main method

Tags: c#

I'm trying to have a "ToString()-method" return the full name of a customer

Like

//Console.WriteLine("Your name is " + fName + lName);

already does, but in ToString.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var instance = new Customer();
    }
}
```

--

```
class Customer
{
    public string fName, lName;

    public Customer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first name");
        fName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your last name");
        lName = Console.ReadLine();
        //Console.WriteLine("Your name is " + fName + lName);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return fName + lName;
        Console.WriteLine(fName + lName);
    }
}
```

Any feedback om how to solve this would be much appreciated. Tried putting different things in Main but could never get it to compile even.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(fName + lName);` will never be reached, because `return` statement exits from method.

Comment: The class design is not good at all. Start of by moving out the `Console.ReadLine` and `Console.WriteLine` calls out of the constructor into the main or somewhere else. Then fill the variables of the class from there and call `ToString()` at the end of your code - I think that pretty much covers what you'll like to do in a more charming fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I will agree that design isnt the best and it is not really clear to me, but I will try and help you with couple of variations
1:

```
class Customer
{
    public string fName, lName;
    public Customer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first name");
        fName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your last name");
        lName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(ToString());
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return fName + lName;
    }
}
```

2:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var instance = new Customer();
        Console.WriteLine(instance.ToString());
    }
}
//in Customer class
public override string ToString()
{
    return fName + lName;
}
```

3:
Write printing method in Customer class and call it over ctor like in "1:"